# modernizr and pdf plugin detection

Tags: pdf, web-applications, modernizr

Can modernizer detect whether or not the browser has a pdf plugin installed and enabled?  I'm displaying a pdf in an iframe in a web application.  I remove the iframe from the dom clientside when a pdf plugin isnt present.  I'm using a bit of clunky javascript to do the detection and would like to replace it with something more robust/standard and came across modernizr.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [Modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/#s2) I didn't see any way to detect for pdf plugins, but you can check the mimeTypes the browser can handle. Writting it as a Modernizr test, you could do something like:

```
Modernizr.addTest('pdf', function(){
    var mimes = navigator.mimeTypes;
    for (var i = 0, i_len = mimes.length; i < i_len; i++){
        if (mimes[i].type === 'application/pdf')
            return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

You should then be able to detect if the browser has a pdf plugin by the value of `Modernizr.pdf`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on firefox on linux (might work on windows, as I have not tested). navigator.mimeTypes doesn't contain 'application/pdf', but it supports PDFs in iframe.

Comment: It worked for me on Windows. What are the contents of your navigator.mimeTypes?

Comment: right, I can repro the issue by removing the adobe plugin on FF, which then falls back to its pdf.js (FF19+). This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187902/how-to-detect-if-pdf-js-is-default-reader-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

I don't think modernizr does it, but there's a library called [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com) which attempts to detect the various ways PDFs can be rendered.

Comment: Thats libreary sounds great, but isn't maintained