# How to detect if pdf.js is *default* reader in firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, pdf.js

Since Firefox 19, there is an internal default PDF reader "pdf.js". How can I detect whether this is the reader by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for...

http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/PDFjs/

Comment: I think this is what I am search for. I will check and if I have problems I will post again for feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This will test for it. I can't get to the other link due to corporate firewall. Dunno what it says. Maybe its the same.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bWstc/)

```
<iframe src="some.pdf" id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>
```

.

```
// FireFox test for PDFJS to display PDFs. Works in 20 & 21.
// If you don't test for the browser ...
//    IE says PDFJS is there. It isn't.
//    Chrome hangs on the fiddle
//    Safari for Windows says PDFJS isn't there
$(window).load(function() {

  var userAgent = navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "other";
  if(userAgent.indexOf("firefox") > -1) {

    var $iframe = $("#iframe");
    var $innerDiv;
    try {
      $innerDiv = $iframe.contents().find('div');
      alert("PDFJS not loaded");
    } catch (e) { 
      alert("PDFJS loaded");
    }
  } else {
      alert("Not running in FireFox - no PDFJS available");
  }
});
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Return "PDFJS loaded" even when opening the file in Acrobat Reader...